# MySQL join only if selected rows have same value, else return null

Tags: mysql

I have the following columns: id, parent_id, customer_id.
I would like to select all parents rows with customer_id which should have value of cells if parent and all child rows have the same value, or null (or 0) if customer_id is not equal in all rows.

| description | id | parent_id | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| this is a parent row | **1** | 0 | 101 |
| this is a child row for row id = 1 | 2 | **1** | 101 |
| this is a child row for row id = 1 | 3 | **1** | 101 |
| this is a parent row | **4** | 0 | 103 |
| this is a child row for row id = 4 | 5 | **4** | 104 |
| this is a child row for row id = 4 | 6 | **4** | 104 |
| this is a parent row | **7** | 0 | 101 |
| this is a child row for row id = 7 | 8 | **7** | 104 |
| this is a child row for row id = 7 | 9 | **7** | 101 |

I am looking for query that will return a result:

| id | customer_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 4 | null (or 0) |
| 7 | null (or 0) |

Thank you all in advance for your help :)

Comment: Do you always have only one level of child? Or can a child also have children?

Comment: Does `customer_id` may contain NULL?

Comment: Just one level (child cannot have children) and customer_id cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-join that table to get a series of rows with the children of each parent, and group by the parent. Then, a neat trick you could use is to get the max and min `customer_id` and use a `case` expression to display them if they are the same or `null` otherwise:

```sql
SELECT   p.id AS id,
         CASE WHEN MAX(c.customer_id) = p.customer_id AND 
                   MIN(c.custoemr_id) = p.customer_id
              THEN p.customer_id
              END AS customer_id
FROM     mytable p
JOIN     mytable c ON p.id = c.parent_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.customer_id
```

Note that the grouping on `p.customer_id` essentially does nothing to the grouping because `p.id` is unique for each parent anyway, but it allows us to avoid non-group expression errors in the select list.

Comment: It works, but for parents that have no children, I changed to  `JOIN mytable c ON p.id = c.parent_id or p.id = c.id and c.parent_id = 0`. Thank you very much!